# How can you have two URL routes mapped to the same handler method in Spring MVC (3.0)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-routing, code-duplication

I have a a `userPanel` method mapped to the `/user/panel` URL route:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/panel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String userPanel(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model)
```

However, I would also like the `userPanel` method to handle the route `/panel` without creating a separate method such as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/panel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String panel(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model)
```

Is there a way to have the `userPanel` method handle both routes to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@RequestMapping` can take multiple paths:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user/panel", "/panel"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String userPanel(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model)
```